# AWS image processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am working on a project where I need to take a picture of a surface using my phone and then analyze the surface for defects and marks.

I want to take the image and then send it to the cloud for analysis.
Does AWS-Rekognition provide such a service to analyze the defects I want to study?
Or Would I need to write a custom code using opencv or something?

Comment: a simple machine learning classifier will do this job if you can provide good amount of quality training data

Answer (score 2):

While Amazon Rekognition can detect faces and objects, it has no idea what it meant by a "defect".

Imagine if you had 10 people lined up and showed them a picture, asking them if they could see a defect. Would they all agree? They'd probably ask you what you mean by a defect and how bad something has to look before it could be considered a defect.

Similarly, you would need to **train** a system on what is a valid defect and what is **not** a defect.

This is a good use case for [Amazon SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/). You would need to provide LOTS of sample images of defects and not-defects. They should be shot from many different angles in many different lighting situations, similar to the images you would want to test.

It would then build a model that could be used for detecting 'defects' in supplied images. You could even put the model into an [AWS DeepLens unit](https://aws.amazon.com/deeplens/) to do the processing locally.

Please note, however, that you need to provide a large number of images (hundreds is good, thousands is better) to be able to train it to correct detect 'defects'.